# Is there a way to avoid using ._1 to be more readable

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I'm doing something like the following code in Scala language.

```
val newCars = existingCars.filter(_.id > 0).map((_.name, _.plate, _.date))
val filteredCars = newCars.filter(_._1 != 0 && _._2.isEmpty && _._3.isEmpty)
```

Is there a way to avoid the use of _._1, _._2 and _._3 to be more readable?

There is something in Scala language like the following code?

```
val newCars = existingCars.filter(_.id > 0).map((_.name, _.plate, _.date))
val filteredCars = newCars.
    filter((id, name, date) => id != 0 && name.isEmpty && date.isEmpty)
```

Comment: `filter(case (a, b, c) => ... )`

Comment: I don't think `map((_.name, _.plate, _.date))` works the way you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use partial functions

```
newCars.filter {
  case (id, name, date) => id != 0 && name.isEmpty && date.isEmpty
}
```

Partial functions can also be defined outside your filter, composed and reused.

If you happen to use that particular format you could be interested in case classes. If you already know them, maybe you should know that you can build them directly from tuple using the `.tupled` method

```
.map(x=>MyCaseClass.tupled(x))
```

Comment: I love this part of scala!

Answer (score 1):

To add to the other answers, you may want to use `collect` which combines a `filter` and a `map`.  Remember to use curly-braces `{}` when you use `case`.

You could do something like:

```
val newCars = List( 
  ("123ABC", "Chevy", "2016"), 
  ("234BCD","Ford","2016"), 
  ("345DEF","","")
)

val filteredCars = newCars.collect{ 
  case (id,name,date) if id.nonEmpty && name.isEmpty && date.isEmpty =>
    (id,name,date)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your code won't compile: you have `map` take a tuple of 3 functions, and `filter` take a function with 3 parameters. I assume you meant

```
val newCars = existingCars.filter(_.id > 0).map(x => (x.name, x.plate, x.date))
val filteredCars = newCars.filter(x => x._1 != 0 && x._2.isEmpty && x._3.isEmpty)
```

For this case I'd suggest simply filtering first:

```
existingCars.filter(_.id > 0).filter(car => car.name != 0 && car.plate.isEmpty && car.date.isEmpty).map(car => (car.name, car.plate, car.date))
```

(presumably something is mixed up in the condition given in your question, since `_._1` corresponds to `name`, not to `id`). And then you can simplify the two `filter`s:

```
existingCars.filter(car => car.id > 0 && car.name != 0 && car.plate.isEmpty && car.date.isEmpty).map(car => (car.name, car.plate, car.date))
```